# Run java bundled in .app from command-line

Tags: terminal, command-line, java

The question is how do I run some application written in java and bundled into *.app* package from command-line?

The main purpose of this is to run an application under JDK7. So I will start it with the `java` bundled in JDK7 instead of default one.

I need something like https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10253/15553 but with java, so I can run it with a different JDK.

Comment: You're better of using a *.jar, then a *.app.  App bundles are made specifically for objective-c/c/c++ and so on. You might be able to create a makeshift app, but that would be pointless because you would have to run it manually anyway

Comment: $Java /Applications[...]/*.app/[...]/java-executable Is this what you mean? Because from my experience this won't work.

Comment: You're best option is creating an app package that launches the java app using c, using the exec family of functions

Comment: @rubixibuc I have NetBeans.app. And I need to run it under JDK7. Is the any way of doing in except for making `/usr/bin/java` to point a `java` binary in JDK7 bundle?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what I would do if you know c or objective-c, is just have the binary launch the file with exec().  http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to another JVM, try to modify the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` shell environment variable in ~/.profile.

```
# in ~/.profile
# switch to another JVM (here, 1.7)
unset JAVA_HOME PATH
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -F --version 1.7 2>/dev/null)"
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"

# general info on Java preferences
open -a 'Java Preferences'
```

Comment: It's a nice idea. But I'm looking for a solution to run just one app with a different java. Thou making the script that will switch java, launch app and switch if back is also an option. Anyway the problem is solved because Netbeans unix-executable binary allows to set a home of JDK as a parameter. But the question is still interesting, and you have pointed out the best working solution this far.

Answer (score 1):

Or open the .app file and edit or add the `JVMVersion`value in the Info.plist like so

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6+</string>
```

Comment: Not working. Neither `1.6+` nor `1.7+`

Comment: Maybe you are missing some other Java Keys there. Have a look at [this Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html)