# How to open files in another app via Terminal on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to open videos and pictures from my command line shell.

Is there a way terminal app can do this?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

To open any file from the command line with the default application, just type `open` followed by the filename/path.

Example:

```
open ~/Desktop/filename.mp4
```

**Edit:** as per Johnny Drama's comment below, if you want to be able to open files in a certain application, put `-a` followed by the application's name in quotes between `open` and the file.

Example:

```
open -a "QuickTime Player" ~/Desktop/filename.mp4
```

If you need further information about the `open` command, type `man open`.

Comment: Just to complete this answer: With timotyhm's command you will open the file with the default application for this filetype. If you want to open any file with a specific application, just enter: `open -a "Application" /Path/to/file`. Example: `open -a "Adobe Photoshop CC 2014" ~/Desktop/test.psd`. See `man open` for more information.

Comment: @JohnnyDrama Good point. Can I edit that into my answer?

Comment: The collaboration in answers is awesome. Johnny Drama's answer is what I really wanted, but the title is what I searched. Answers like these are why I love StackExchange!

Comment: This does not work. 18.04. jpg.

Comment: To complete the answer even more, if you have multiple apps with the same name (e.g. you're developing and have an app store version and a debug version), you can specify a path to the app. Example: `open -a /path/to/MyApp.app /path/to/file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a guide on [how to open a file in terminal](https://owlcation.com/stem/how-to-open-files-in-terminal) which includes instructions for Windows and Linux as well, but to summarize for both the OP and others who find this page (to be complete, I showed how to do this in command prompt as well):

**Navigate to the file's directory**:
`cd /path/to/directory`

**Open the file**:
In macOS
`open filename.txt` or use editors like vi, emacs, nano. Example:

```
vi filename.txt
```

Opening Other Files in Terminal:

macOS:
PDFs: `open filename.pdf`

Images: `open filename.jpg`

Webpages: `open http://www.example.com`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m not so sure the windows or Linux information will be greeted with up votes here. Perhaps linking to that detail hosted on another site as a footnote would be more appropriate?

Comment: @bmike thank you, I have removed the information for linux and windows

Comment: @agarza thank you for the edit. It looks great!

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by using `xdg-open filename`.
Command will open the file with it's default application and it also used to open the urls .

Comment: `xdg-open` is not a stock Mac OS X tool.

Comment: `xdg-open` is on Linux and macOS is not Linux! The accepted answer has the default macOS command line app, `open`.

Comment: Awkwardly this question is the top google hit for "linux open any file". So while this is not a correct answer for the question asked, it is really handy to have this listed highly. I can't bring myself to vote this answer up, but I will vote the other wrong answers down to ensure this stays prominent.

Comment: You’re correct @LovesTha - would it be good to ask and answer a question on Linux or Unix specific sites here so it can be found better and be on topic?