# Open file in Numbers via terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

I'm trying to open a file in Numbers via terminal. I found the suggested command here: [How to open files via Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212583/how-to-open-files-via-terminal)

So I tried:

```
open -a "Numbers" filepath/filename
```

And I get:

```
bash: open: command not found
```

As a test I used open to simply open a photo via terminal and that worked fine so I'm not sure where I went wrong above.

Comment: Can you just copy/paste the command from the question into Terminal and try again (with a real path/name of course)? If open sometimes works and sometimes doesn't you just may have a typo somewhere

Comment: what does `type -a open` show? Is `/usr/bin` in your $PATH?

Comment: I forgot I was SSHing into a live server to access the file. I'm guessing that's why I couldn't open it. Downloaded it and was able to use the command as written to open it in Numbers. Thank you for the replies, they helped me realize what was going on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is effectively a user error - ie ssh means that open does not work. The user has not come back and edited the question and added his comment as an answer which would be useful for others in the same state. As the question does not mention it we get answers wasting they time on it,

Comment: The error message itself just tells you that `open` is not in your PATH (and not a function or alias either). It does not say whether or not  `open` would do something reasonable if you are in a ssh shell. Probably it wouldn't, but this is not the point here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Monterey and I get Numbers open with:

```
open <path>/<file>.csv
```

Comment: The issue is solved - see Jack's last comment - it does not work if you are not running in the desktop.