# How to open a Microsoft Word document from the command line in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, ms-office

In earlier iterations of `macOS` I would use

`open -a Finder.app <filename>`

In `Sonoma` that is resulting in two of the following dialog boxes :

> The application "Microsoft Word" can't be opened
> -128

[image]

Note: the same document can be successfully opened directly from `Finder.app` by double clicking or hitting <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>  . So `Word` is functioning properly and the document is intact.

I did look at some `microsoft-learn` pages and they do not address this scenario.

How to open a Microsoft Word document from the commandline in Sonoma?

Comment: What's wrong with `open path/to/doc`? Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212583/how-to-open-files-in-another-app-via-terminal-on-macos

Comment: @Tetsujin  That actually works in `sonoma`: it did not in earlier iterations of `macOS`.

Comment: It worked in 2015, as per the linked answer!

Comment: @WestCoastProjects It's essentially equivalent to double clicking on the document, so it should have worked forever. The only issue would be if you changed the "open with" application for the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would type `open`  then drag the document to the shell. (Skip the app entirely)

See if the full path opens, no need to involve Finder. Worst case specify “Microsoft Word” as the [app to open the document](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212585/5472).

Comment: yea that works now. In past iterations it did not. thanks.

Comment: Wonderful @WestCoastProjects launch services can be odd indeed…

Answer (score 14):

I think that `-a Finder.app` is an incorrect syntax. You don't want to open it 'in' the Finder, you want to open it in Word.

The following works for me in Sonoma:

`open -a "Microsoft Word.app" document.docx`

`open document.docx` (as Word is the default).

That having been said, `open -a Finder.app document.docx` also works for me in Sonoma, briefly revealing a Finder window of the enclosing folder, before Word then launches and the file is loaded.

Obviously, this is for a document.docx that's in the current directory, or contains a full filepath.

It's possible that it's not working for you because of a Launch Services DB corruption, or a file cache or something.

Comment: The `open -a <app name>` syntax has apparently changed.  I used `Finder.app` because that did actually work [better] for several iterations of `macOS`.  Apparently simply `open` is fine now.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects The man page for `open` is dated 2017. I've used those options for many years. I'd recommend resetting your LaunchServices database.

Comment: The open syntax for this has not changed since 2000 (and I suspect since 1990 from NeXT)

Comment: I don’t think that `.app` is necessary.

Comment: @CarstenS The example in the man pages includes it, but you're right, it isn't necessary.