# How can I launch a GUI app in Applications folder from command line?

Tags: terminal, applications

I would like to launch a GUI app that is in the `Applications` folder from the command line as opposed to clicking the icon in the `Finder` or in the `Dock`.  The reason I want that is to be able to launch it as `root` using `sudo` as opposed to launching it as my default user.

When I went into the Applications, this is what it looked like:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app@16:16:42>ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 myuser  admin    340 Dec 17 14:07 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 68 root           admin   2312 Jan 20 18:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x@  6 myuser  admin    204 Dec 17 14:08 Contents
-rw-r--r--@  1 myuser  admin  11358 Dec 17 14:06 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 myuser  admin    127 Dec 17 14:06 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 myuser  admin    476 Dec 17 14:09 bin
-rw-r--r--@  1 myuser  admin     10 Dec 17 14:01 build.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 85 myuser  admin   2890 Dec 17 14:06 lib
drwxr-xr-x@ 29 myuser  admin    986 Dec 17 14:06 license
drwxr-xr-x@ 30 myuser  admin   1020 Dec 17 14:06 plugins
```

Funny thing is, in the `Finder`, `IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE` shows as a clickable icon which launches the app.  But at the terminal level, it is actually a directory with contents I do not know how to navigate and manipulate to emulate a GUI click.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4240

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `open`:

```
open "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app"
```

```
open -a "IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE"
```

---

However, prepending `sudo` isn't enough to run as root. You'll need to run the actual binary:

```
sudo /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName
```

Comment: If you use the -a flag for the `open` command you don't need the path.

Comment: Yes, but giving the full path will always work regardless of where the app is located. Either way, I've added it.

Comment: I didn't have to use open.

Comment: I've never had the -a flag fail. Apps don't have to be located in /Applications for it to work. I can open stuff I've written that is buried somewhere in ~/Library/ without a problem. The only issue is if there is more than one copy of an app then I'm not sure which one will open.

Comment: @Mark I've had trouble with -a for apps on network drives, although I suppose that is an edge case.

Comment: I can see that, but it's not something I've ever tried.

Comment: Just a warning that some apps don't like their executable run directly without passing them some options on the command line. Isn't there a plist somewhere that defines the options that get passed to the executable when it is run as an app?

Comment: The Info.plist file inside the Contents directory of the App may define, e.g., environment variables that should be set. Running the executable directly will bypass this.

Answer (score 3):

Just 'cd' into the application bundle, then into the `Contents` folder, and then into the `MacOS` folder. There should be an executable file in there which you can run normally. If there are multiple executable files in there, you could look at the `Contents/Info.plist` file inside the application bundle, and look for the entry `CFBundleExecutable`, which indicates the executable file that is launched when you double-click the application bundle in Finder.